# How to set false this regex?

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

```
§0§0((?:§[1-9a-d])+)§e§f
```

Will work if string contains, for example, §0§0§e§f or §0§0§1§e§f or §0§0§1§b§e§f or etc., but I need to check if that example is false. What I tried but not work:

```
?!§0§0((?:§[1-9a-d])+)§e§f
[^(§0§0((?:§[1-9a-d])+)§e§f)]
!§0§0((?:§[1-9a-d])+)§e§f
(^§0§0((?:§[1-9a-d])+)§e§f)
```

and something else.

Comment: Why not using a boolean check in the code itself? If it matches, return `false`. And the regex must look like `(§0§0(?:(?:§[1-9a-d])*)§e§f)`, I guess, for it to match the strings you mention.

Comment: Technically, I can't do boolean check. Is your example will false if regex like §0§0§e§f with no symbols between §0§0 and §e§f?

Comment: The regex you posted does not match `§0§0§e§f`. Please check for yourself on http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Comment: Set to false regex posted in first comment not work.

Comment: That regex is not to negate, it is your regex that is fixed :) Please update your post if you agree.

Comment: I have this code: http://pastebin.com/3amzBbM6 and need to execute code on lines 23-42 only by editing regular expression

Comment: even if string equals 123abc

Comment: Just a side note: you have `(§0§0(?:(?:§[1-9a-d])*)§e§f)` regex on your site (the final `?!` is a trace of your experiments I guess). In the post, you have `§0§0((?:§[1-9a-d])+)§e§f` and it does not match `§0§0§e§f`. OK, now it is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex with `MULTILINE` option to check for *lines* that *do not* contain your previous pattern:

```
^(?!.*§0§0(?:(?:§[1-9a-d])*)§e§f).*$
```

It won't match the following *lines*:

```
§0§0§e§f
§0§0§e§f
§0§0§1§e§f
§0§0§1§b§e§f
```

It will match the following lines:

```
string
another string 
more strings
```